# MySQL COUNT,GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY together

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table like following.

```
IP Host Label BotName
1  A    good    aa
1  A    good    aa
2  C    good    bb
3  C    bad     cc
4  D    bad     dd
4  D    bad     ee
5  E    good    ff
5  E    good    gg
```

I want to get the output like following.

```
count Host BotName  Type
2     A    aa       good
1     C    bb       good
1     C    cc       bad
2     D    dd,ee    bad
2     E    ff,gg    good
```

Conditions are:

1. Count IPs groupby Host and Label
2. If the botnames are different concatenate them using commas.

Following is which I have tried, but couldn't get expected results.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(BotName) name FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(IP) FROM mytable GROUP BY Host,Label)q");
```

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This is a problem.

Comment: I posted answer with sql fiddle have you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count and GROUP_CONCAT will get the values, but you need to group by the Host and label / type fields.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS `count`, Host, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Botname) AS Botname, label AS type
FROM name
GROUP BY Host, type
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`,
       HOST,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct boatname) BotName,
       label as Type
FROM temp
GROUP BY host,label
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9511/3)

Comment: I suspect you want a DISTINCT in there.

Comment: @Sadikhasan: Thank you very much Sadikhasan, Your answer is very similar to Kickstart's one and working perfectly. I have accepted his answer. Thanks for the Fiddle. :)